# Receive SMS on twillion phone number

Tags: sms, twilio

I have attached call back URL in the Twilio account with the Twilio phone number. But still i am not getting a hit on the call back URL when sending SMS to twilio number. There is no history in Twilio about the message received, though it is showing sent from my mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

I did a work around to recieve messages.

In a background thread, I am continuously listening to see if the 'number of messages' changed:

```
def newMsgCame(self,client,old_len):
        new_len = len(client.messages.list(to="<my twilio number>"))
        if(new_len > old_len):
            return True,new_len
        return False,new_len
```

If yes, then I return the latest message:

```
def getMsg(self,client):
    messages = client.messages.list(to="<my twilio number>")
    if (len(messages) != 0):
        return messages[0].body
    return ""
```

This might fail in many scenarios though.